# Special character using mod rewrites

Tags: mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have an url with https://uat.com/content/mam/web/gc/jcr:content.model.news.json/languageCode=de/countryCode=de/tags=%5B%22web%3Aeditorial%2Fcitytrip%22%2C%22web%3Aeditorial%2Fsightseeing%22%5D/currentPage=1/entryAmount=10
in which while hitting in the browser its giving 404 error.
If we use tags=["web:editorial/citytrip","web:editorial/sightseeing"]/currentPage=1/entryAmount=10 instead of tags=%5B%22web%3Aeditorial%2Fcitytrip%22%2C%22web%3Aeditorial%2Fsightseeing%22%5D/currentPage=1/entryAmount=10
Its giving me correct result.

In my aem-ssl-redirect.conf , the rewrite rule is written like this :

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]

Please help me to change the rewrite rule so that my initial url becomes accessible and its not blocked httpd server.

I tried to change it with

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L,B]

but didn't make any help.